# ReactJS - updating components when separate class property is changed

Tags: javascript, html, class, dom, reactjs

In my project I have an html doc with some react code, for instance:

```
var Test = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {storage: this.props.storage};
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <h2>
        {this.state.storage}
      </h2>
    );
  }
});
```

In another class, AppMan, I have a property called `storageLeft`. If I render the Test component like:

```
<Test storage={AppMan.storageLeft}/>
```

What is the correct way to go about updating the `Test` component whenever `storageLeft` is changed inside the AppMan class? I'm not sure if passing it as a property of the component is the right way to go about it. Initially, all I can think of is doing a setInterval and constantly doing `this.setState({storage: AppMan.storageLeft});` or something along those lines. Any better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Setting *state* via *props* is an [anti-pattern](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html). You should save `storageLeft` in the AppMan component's state and then pass that state to the Test component as a prop. A component automatically re-renders itself and its children (if needed) when you change its state.

The [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html#reactive-state) state that:

> To implement interactions, we introduce mutable state to the
>   component. this.state is private to the component and can be changed
>   by calling this.setState(). When the state updates, the component
>   re-renders itself.

This way your components stay in sync when you pass state as a prop.

*AppMan.js*

```
<Test storage={this.state.storageLeft} />
```

*Test.js*

```
var Test = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <h2>
        {this.props.storage}
      </h2>
    );
  }
});
```